# SQL Server Config manager error: Cannot connect to WMI provider

Tags: sql-server

I cant open my SQL server configuration manager getting this error message:

```
Cannot connect to WMI provider. You do not have permission or the server is unreachable. Note that you can only manage SQL Server 2005 and later servers with SQL Server Configuration Manager. 
Invalid
```

I have searched online material and ran the mofcomp command as recommended: `mofcomp “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof”`

I am now getting this error message:

```
MOF file has been successfully parsed
Storing data in the repository…
An error occurred while processing item 10 defined on lines 73 – 79 in file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof:
Compiler returned error 0x80070005Error Number: 0x80070005, Facility: Win32
Description: Access is denied.
```

Can you please help me out, been 2 weeks sited with this problem

Comment: Can you ping the server? Has the SQL Server service on the server started?

Comment: @SchmitzIT yes I can ping the server and service is started. Just that I can not run my configuration manager because of the error message pasted above. Seems like its a common problem to SQL server users but cant figure this out.

Comment: Try and run the WMI Diagnosis Utility: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7684. This seems to hint at an OS error. (I found an article for SQL Server 2008, showing the exact second error message you specified): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/956035/error-message-when-you-install-sql-server-2008-an-error-occurred-while-processing-item-10-defined-on-lines-73---79-in-file-c-program-files-microsoft-sql-server-100-shared-sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof

Comment: Also take note that the command you use with mofcomp is version sensitive. What version of SQL Server are you running? If it's 2008, you need to replace \120\ with \100\, for instance

Comment: Thanks @SchmitzIT, I run the WMI Diagnosis utility and got this information:

49190 09:18:02 (1) !! ERROR: The following WMI repository file(s) is/are missing: ......................................................... 4 ERROR(S)!
49191 09:18:02 (0) ** - INDEX.BTR
49192 09:18:02 (0) ** - MAPPING1.MAP
49193 09:18:02 (0) ** - MAPPING2.MAP
49194 09:18:02 (0) ** - OBJECTS.DATA

Comment: There may be a permissions issue in the Registry causing `mofcomp` to fail. If so, Pinal Dave has a solution at: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/05/20/sql-server-configuration-manager-cannot-connect-wmi-provider-not-permission-server-unreachable/

Comment: Sometimes an older version of SQL Server is also installed -- to make sure you're not running an older SQL Server Config Mgr, navigate to it through Start menu folders. This ended up being my problem (seeing the same error)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Run Cmd as **Administrator** and execute these commands:

First go to SQL Shared folder according to your sql version:

SQL 2008:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\
SQL 2012:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Shared\
SQL 2014:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared\
SQL 2017:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Shared\ -------> My version is 2017
SQL 2019:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Shared\

[Find more versions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/file-locations-for-default-and-named-instances-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Shared"
```

Then:

```
mofcomp sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof
```

**Update**:

The problem occurs because the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) provider configuration file for manage SQL Server services is missing. So the `mofcomp` command repairs or recreates it.

Here is more explanation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/mofcomp

Comment: @Arun Prasad E S Care to explain what the command does? Thanks!

Comment: thanks but guys make sure you cd program files (x86) , it make me wrong in first

Comment: Note: look for the version of the Management Studio not your sql server. As you know you may have different versions

Comment: I think this is the best approach

Comment: in sql server 2022 i use mofcomp sqlmgmprovider.mof

Answer (score 10):

Run the @Fereydoon Barkzehy codes with **Administrative** Access

Sample -

```
  cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Shared
  cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Shared
  mofcomp sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof
```

depends on where the file "sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof" is present

[Youtube video](https://youtu.be/aj7iyil4tDU)

Comment: And if that file isn't present in *ANY* of my Shared folders for any of my versions of SQL Server? :)

Answer (score 3):

The best solution for me was to uninstall the instance and reinstall a fresh instance. This worked 100%.

Comment: that did not succeed, but the accepted solution worked

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue but it is not working at first. Second I already restarted my PC but it is not working either. What I found out is that you will run this on the folder where your **SQL Server Management Studio** is installed and not on the **MS SQL Instance** folder.

My SQL Server Management Studio which is 2016 is installed in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130
```

But I keep on running changing folder on which I installed on my SQL Server 2012 instance:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Shared\
```

After that, just run the command: `mofcomp sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof` as everyone suggest in here.

So keep it mind the folder since that may affect your troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you. I had exactly the same problem. I have SQL server 2016 but running the command in folder \130 does not help. I have to run it in \110. I hope someone could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

doing a fresh OS installation also worked for me as well. but this is a pain. Sometimes you can run the:

```
“C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof”
```

Sometimes it helps and sometimes it doesn't, all you need to do is do a fresh OS installation and then SQL installation.

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error I finally found this working solution:

1. I searched all `sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof` files under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server`
2. Running CMD as administrator I did for each result found above:

   i) Change directory to go to the directory

   ii) Run `mofcomp sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof`
3. Reboot

Then, it works.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to download the SQLEXPR_x64_Enu, run the Setup.exe and use the Repair option.